# Difficult between atmega328 & atmega2560 when coding & compiling in a pure c

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, atmega328

I have an arduino uno with atmega328p controller.

I found the code to deal with some specific uart protocol, named mdb: https://github.com/Bouni/MateDealer/tree/master/arduino

But it's compiled just for atmega2560 controller: https://github.com/Bouni/MateDealer/blob/master/arduino/makefile#L42

If I replace it by `atmega328p` or `atmega328`, I get the error:

```
asiniy@misha:~/projects/MateDealer/arduino$ make all

-------- begin --------
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Compiling: main.c
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega328 -I. -gdwarf-2   -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=main.lst  -std=gnu99 -DF_OSC=16000000 -MD -MP -MF .dep/main.o.d main.c -o main.o

Compiling: usart.c
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega328 -I. -gdwarf-2   -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-adhlns=usart.lst  -std=gnu99 -DF_OSC=16000000 -MD -MP -MF .dep/usart.o.d usart.c -o usart.o
usart.c:25:40: error: ‘UBRR1H’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     { { { {}, 0, 0 }, { {}, 0, 0 } }, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C },
                                        ^
usart.c:25:49: error: ‘UBRR1L’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     { { { {}, 0, 0 }, { {}, 0, 0 } }, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C },
                                                 ^
usart.c:25:58: error: ‘UCSR1B’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     { { { {}, 0, 0 }, { {}, 0, 0 } }, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C },
                                                          ^
usart.c:25:67: error: ‘UCSR1C’ undeclared here (not in a function)
     { { { {}, 0, 0 }, { {}, 0, 0 } }, &UBRR1H, &UBRR1L, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C },
                                                                   ^
In file included from usart.c:14:0:
usart.c: In function ‘USART0_RX_vect’:
usart.c:185:5: warning: ‘USART0_RX_vect’ appears to be a misspelled signal handler [enabled by default]
 ISR(USART0_RX_vect){
     ^
usart.c: In function ‘USART1_RX_vect’:
usart.c:197:5: warning: ‘USART1_RX_vect’ appears to be a misspelled signal handler [enabled by default]
 ISR(USART1_RX_vect){
     ^
usart.c:203:12: error: ‘UDR1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     data = UDR1;
            ^
usart.c:203:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from usart.c:14:0:
usart.c: In function ‘USART0_UDRE_vect’:
usart.c:233:5: warning: ‘USART0_UDRE_vect’ appears to be a misspelled signal handler [enabled by default]
 ISR(USART0_UDRE_vect){
     ^
usart.c: In function ‘USART1_UDRE_vect’:
usart.c:253:5: warning: ‘USART1_UDRE_vect’ appears to be a misspelled signal handler [enabled by default]
 ISR(USART1_UDRE_vect){
     ^
usart.c:261:31: error: ‘TXB81’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                 UCSR1B |= (1<<TXB81);
                               ^
usart.c:266:9: error: ‘UDR1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         UDR1 = data;
         ^
usart.c:269:20: error: ‘UDRIE1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     UCSR1B &= ~(1<<UDRIE1);
                    ^
make: *** [usart.o] Error 1
```

I've tried to play with compilers (default is gnu99) and so on, but with no success. Why I have this trouble? How can I compile this code for upload it to arduino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the MateDealer project and I never had the intention to port it to other boards than the Arduino Mega2560!

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is absolutely right, the Arduino Mega2560 is the only board with more than 1 serial port (Yes there is the Due and the Leonardo, but those would require major changes to the code).

The fastest way to get the code running is by using a Mega2560, but be warned, the code might be bugy as hell ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The '328 only has a single USART. You will need to remove all references to USARTs beyond the first as well as the numeric suffix from the USART register names in order to get it to compile.

Comment: So, do you mean that I can't read data from MDB protocol and send it to the serial port of my computer to read it in the display?

Comment: If you require more than one USART to do so then no, you can't. You could try a serial UART, but this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Can I use one usart for connect mdb and the second one for connect to serial of my computer?

Comment: Again, you don't have 2 USARTs.

Comment: SoftwareSerial library give me ability to  connect by 2 uarts, but not in the same time. I need to stop 1st usart, then run 2nd. How do you think, can I implement something like this in pure c?

Comment: You do have one hardware USART, as an uplink to the PC.

Comment: So, can I use one hardware UART to connect to the computer, and another one to connect to mdb?

Comment: You still only have one hardware USART. You will need to use a software UART as well.

Comment: So, can I implement connection from uno both to computer and mdb? Just yes or no, please